# How to append dynamic data with jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have a form that is created dynamically which posts data to a database and returns a response with ajax and appends this data to a table row. I can see with firebug that the response is working but it is not appending the data to my table. I have got this working but I am currently trying to get the returned data to append to the same table row. Can anyone tell me what is wrong?

Here is my jquery.

```
$(document).on('submit', '.myForm', '.results', function(e) {    
    var new_data = $("#" + $(this).data("table")).find('tbody > tr')    
    e.preventDefault();        
    $.ajax({
        url: 'add_tag_test.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'html',
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function(response) {
            $(new_data).hide().fadeIn("slow").append('<td>' + response + '</td>');        
            $('#message').show().fadeIn();
            $('#message').fadeOut("slow");        
        }        
    });

    return false;
});
```

Here is the submit button on my dynamic form:

```
<span class="pull-right"><button type="submit" data-table="myTable'.$i.'" class="fabutton"></button></span>
```

This is the response that I am getting that is not appending itself:

```
     <td><small><a href="profile.php?user_name=Julian" 
 <span class="" id=".6.">Julian,&nbsp;</small></a></td>
```

Comment: does `new_data` properly hold the table `tr` element?

Comment: That's very strange to add a simple column to a row.. You don't need a new row?! Then, what is the new_data value? Does it point to the right dom element?

Comment: new_data.hide().fadeIn("slow").append('<td>' + response + '</td>');  new_data is already jQuery object, you don't need to wrap it in $(), try without and see will it work.

Comment: @Imaginaroom there is no difference if you wrap a Jquery object again with a Jquery object, Its all the same, It gives a jquery object itself, So removing it and trying is of no use as it yields the same result.

Comment: Is there a way to check if new_data is holding the tr element?

Comment: ensure that you are actually matching the dom object you want to manipulate, try to console.log it by calling .html()

Comment: you can use `debugger` and check the values

Comment: console.log(new_data) prints out [] but I'm not sire if I'm logging the correct way.

Comment: `console.log(new_data).length`  what does this print? it must print 1 if a tr is selected else it will be 0

Comment: console.log(new_data).length prints out [ ]

Comment: @JulianJ length will print out number.. that output is not possible.. Here is what you can do to debug this.. add this keyword `debugger;` just below the `var new_data` line of code, Press F12 to open your browser developer window, Now submit the form and the code stops here to debug, You can then see what the value is in `new_data` wither by placing your mouse on it or open console window and paste this and hit enter 'new_data'. Let me know what you see

Comment: Ok, I get ReferenceError: new_data is not defined.

Comment: I've been experimenting with console.log(variables).length and understand it better but just can't get any value for console.log(new_data).length

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming then the objective here is to add columns to an existing table? Something I'd try, in an attempt to (hopefully!) simplify the process a bit:

Construct a function for your submit buttons to piggy-back off of, and then (as I'm assuming you're trying to achieve), send the serialized data from the form that the button is contained in:

```
<button
    type='submit'
    onclick='return submitClicked(this, "myTable<?php echo $i;?>");'
    class='fabutton'>Click Me</button>

    ...

<script>

    function submitClicked(button, table_id){

        button = $(button);
        var form = button.parents('form:first');
        var rows = $('#'+table_id).find('tbody > tr');

        $.ajax({
            url: 'add_tag_test.php',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'html',
            data: form.serialize(),
            success: function(response) {
                rows.hide().append('<td>' + response + '</td>').fadeIn("slow");
                $('#message').fadeIn();
                $('#message').fadeOut("slow");        
            }
        });

        return false;
    }

</script>
```

So we're creating a re-usable function, sending the button and the form ID as parameters to it, and using the button to retrieve the form it's contained in to pass the serialized form data to your `add_tag_test.php` file (I'm assuming you weren't trying to serialize the button itself as your previous code seemed to do).

Then we post the data, get the result, and append it as before. I hope this makes sense, and I tried to simplify it as much as possible!